# How can i apply my own css style in ui Material Textfield?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, next.js

i am working on next js project where i should create a form for registration with specific styles.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to customize a `textField` with my own css. I tried to use `makeStyles` function but the problem is that I should pass objects to `makeStyles` and some properties does not exist like background-color, border-radius etc ...

this is the css i want to apply:

```
.Name {
  width: 535px;
  height: 61px;
  flex-grow: 0;
  margin: 40px 100px 20px 0;
  padding: 19px 329px 20px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: solid 1px var(--select-border);
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

i putted this css in a file which i import in my component as styles and call it in className like
this :

```
   <TextField
        className={styles.Name}
        placeholder='Nom de votre restaurant'
       >
```

and i tried with makeStyles this way :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
nameStyles: {
width:' 535px',
height:' 61px',
flexGrow:'0',
margin:'40px 100px 20px 0',
padding: '19px 329px 20px 20px',
border: '8px',
border: 'solid 1px var(--select-border)',
backgroundColor:' #ffffff',
})
   
   export default function RestaurantRegistration() {
   const classes = useStyles()

   return (
    <React.Fragment>
  
  
   <TextField
    className={classes.nameStyles}
    placeholder='Restaurant Name'
   >
 

   </TextField>
 )
 }
```

With the second way I had to change properties who have '-' in their names because I got a syntax error. For example I changed flex-grow with flexGrow, background-color with backroundColor. I don't know if that is even right. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: If you have just copy-pasted your code, this will give you an error, because you are missing one closing curly bracket for "nameStyles". As far as I can tell, your syntax is right and the camelCase way of naming those variables is needed, because you are writing in ts which gets converted to css later on.
Adding a more detailled analysis (console log etc.) to your code will more likely get you an answer.

Comment: Also, what I just saw is that if you don't write anything in your Textfield, this one should be a self closing tag with following syntax: <TextField className={classes.nameStyles} placeholder='Restaurant Name' />

Comment: i tried so many ways but i am not getting the result i want i don't now what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `className` successful you need to wrap your component with `StylesProvider` with the property `injectFirst`.

also, if you check [TextField API](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#textfield-api) you can use `classes` prop which is an object that can override or extend its styles. You can use the `root` rule name to pass your styles to TextField.

with css modules and stylesProvider:

```
  <StylesProvider injectFirst> 
    <TextField
        className={styles.Name}
        placeholder='Nom de votre restaurant'
       >
  </StylesProvider>
```

with makeStyles:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width:'535px',
    height:'61px',
    flexGrow:'0',
    margin:'40px 100px 20px 0',
    padding: '19px 329px 20px 20px',
    border: '8px',
    border: 'solid 1px var(--select-border)',
    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
}})
   
export default function RestaurantRegistration() {
   const classes = useStyles()

   return (
    <TextField
      classes={classes}
      placeholder='Restaurant Name'
    />
 )
}
```

[image: so-textfields]

Comment: None of these two ways worked for me , plus with the second way i don't have one textField i got many so i have to style each one differently so classes={classes} won't do the job .

Comment: @Ghost I created a sandbox with implementation for both cases

Comment: you can actually use `StylesProvider` to inject first your className, I added to the answer

Comment: for makestyle you can add different names than root than pass as `classes={{ root: classes.firstStyle }}` and so on

Comment: This is much better , but do you have an idea about how to remove the line inside the Input ? it is like you are putting the TextField inside a box

Comment: TextField accepts `InputProps`, an object with Props applied to the Input element, you can check here https://material-ui.com/api/input/. you could pass like `InputProps={{ className: styles.inputClass }}` where you could remove the line, which I believe is a border-bottom applied to the :before element you are talking about